# Date custom format issue when opening an EPPlus generated Excel file on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, excel, ipad, epplus

1. I generate an Excel file using EPPLUS.
2. It has a date column with CustomFormat.
3. I can open this file using Excel (desktop) as well on Android devices without any problem.
4. But if I open this file (e-mail attachment) on iPAD/iPhone the date changes to Number.
5. If I open and save this file in desktop Excel and
   6 Then open this on iPAD/iPhone, the dates are fine
6. If a generate a new file using desktop EXCEL.
7. Just Open and save it using EPPLUS (no content changes)
   9  Then open it on iPAD/iPhone, the date is again changes to Numbers.
8. There seems to be some header problem while saving the file in EPPLUS.

Any help shall be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is your custom date format?

Comment: It is hh:mm dd/mm/yyyy OR hh:mm mm/dd/yyyy, depending upon the user preference. I have found the solution to the problem. Using the latest 4.0 beta version resolves the issue. But thus version has a problem with merged cells and autosize column method.